Is there a run command to open volume or calendar from the Windows 10/11 system tray?
Is there such a run command to open the popup boxes from the system tray for volume and calendar?


Much like how one can run start ms-availablenetworks: in order to open the tray popup for available networks for the system tray rather than pressing the Wi-Fi button.

You can use keyboard shortcuts or ms-settings links.

ms-settings:apps-volume and ms-settings:sound open two Volume Control Panels in the WindowsR dialog, or as a Desktop Shortcut.

For Calendar, use WindowsAltD on Windows 10, or WindowsN on Win 11. However, to view the CPL to set time, use ms-settings:dateandtime.


See also Micosoft's list of other ms-settings.

Open Classic Master Volume slider with the following command 1 -
%SystemRoot%\System32\sndvol.exe -f


Use Win + R to open the Run dialogue box, paste the above command and click OK.
Create a shortcut for above command by using right click on desktop > New > Shortcut, paste above command, click on Next, name the shortcut as per your needs and click Finish.


If you wish to use this frequently,

Right click on the shortcut > Properties > assign Shortcut key, or
Use AutoHotkey to assign shortcut for Run A_WinDir "\System32\sndvol.exe -f" command.

Note:
The slider tends to automatically disappear when it loses focus.
I use the following AutoHotkey script to keep it visible.
#Requires AutoHotkey v2.0

!r:: { ; Alt + R shortcut
Run A_WinDir "\System32\sndvol.exe -f"
If WinWait("ahk_exe sndvol.exe",, 2) ; 2s timeout
    MouseMove_clientCenter("ahk_exe sndvol.exe")
Else MsgBox "WinWait timed out!"
}

MouseMove_clientCenter(HWND := "A") {
WinGetClientPos , , &OutWidth, &OutHeight, HWND
MouseMove OutWidth / 2, OutHeight /2
}

To adjust position of resulting window, visit this SU answer for instructions.
Bonus

Open Classic Audio Devices with the following command -
%SystemRoot%\System32\sndvol.exe -p


Open Classic Volume Mixer with the following command -
%SystemRoot%\System32\sndvol.exe -m




No.
The closest would be to press some keys:

Win + B to access tray area
→ to move to correct icon, assuming their number never changes
Enter to open the UI for the icon

You can simulate that with e.g. SendKeys in PowerShell or AutoHotkey. There are also libraries for tray icons for AHK, like this one with TrayIcon_Button function to click tray icons based on .exe, but not sure if and how well they work in current versions.
